# IE 11 flickering in process flow CRM online 2015 +

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I currently use CRM online 2015 and get the option set "flickering" when I try to change the value only on IE 11.

If I activate the "legacy mode" the flickering is not there.

I try some post to forece rendering by the softawre, an option in IE in the advanced panel.

Nothing work. Any suggestion ?

The problem is there on Win 7, Win 8, Win 10 on IE 11. The problem is not there on Chrome, Edge or Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem is due to the fact that there is no height specified for the div of the main container of the business process flow. When the optionSet opens, it overlaps the main container height size. The solution for this problem is to set the height of the main business process flow div (div with id "processStepsContainer"). I suggest you create a Web Resources that is a Style Sheet(CSS) and that sets this:

```
#processStepsContainer{
  height: 200px;
}
```

Then you just need to use a link on this style. You can do it using a javascript on the load of a form that calls the FixFlicker function:

```
FixFlicker = function(){
  var head = window.parent.window.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  var link = window.parent.window.document.createElement('link');
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  link.type = 'text/css';
  link.href = '/WebResources/theNameOfMyStyleSheet';
  link.media = 'all';
  head.appendChild(link);
}
```

This should solve your problem